# In Zeno of Elea's paradox on the runner, does pausing for a second affect the chances of reaching the limit?

Tags: calculus, limits, paradoxes

Does the sum converge on 1 or is it infinite? 
If it converges on 1, does pausing for a second alter chances of reaching the limit? 
P.S: this is the progressive dichotomy paradox.

Comment: 1) I'm not sure that this is a question suitable for MSE, as it's really a philosophy question, and the answer depends on the interpretation of the question, and 2) I object that calculus solves the heart of the problem as is commonly interpreted. I think too many people interpret it as asking about infinitely many steps, when really it's about the metaphysics of change. Run the paradox packwards. In order to go the first half, he must go a quarter, and in order to go that quarter, he must go an eighth, and so on. The real question is how motion is even possible.

Comment: However, barring the objection above, I don't see how pausing makes any difference in the problem. The issue is how he can move from point a to b. If he pauses , whatever time it took in the scenario without the pause is just increased by the duration of the pause. So really the answer depends on the semantics, as I noted above.

Comment: I was reading Thompson and Gardiner's Calculus Made Easy, and it's mentioned that if the series converges on 1, there are two cases. 1. After each step, the runner pauses for a second, and if this continues for each step, he will never reach the limit. 2. If, instead of waiting, he moves at a steady rate, the discrete process becomes a continuous one, and converges exactly on the limit. How?

Comment: I don't know why Zeno's "Paradox" is still a topic of serious discussion. AFAICT it originally came about because the ancient Greek philosophers were unable to measure the speed of an object. There is no need to get caught up converging series and the like. Assuming constant speeds, Galileo's kinematic equations are all you need to determine precisely when and where the fleet-footed Achilles would catch up to and overtake the lumbering tortoise.

Answer (score 0):

One reason Zeno's paradox is solvable is that we have a converging series in time as well as distance. Assuming constant speed it takes half the time to cover a 1/4 distance vs a 1/2 distance. If you add a fixed length pause after each step then the total time diverges with infinitely many pauses of length n. 
For the time of travel to remain finite, you need the pauses to become briefer with each step so that the sum of the paused time converges also.